# Fractions in a NumericUpDown/DomainUpDown

Tags: c#, numericupdown

Is it possible to display fractions in a NumericUpDown or a DomainUpDown?

I know there are some fonts that have various fraction characters, but I would like to keep my form using Microsoft Sans Serif uniformly.

Comment: Alternatively, if there is a complementary font that looks exactly like Microsoft Sans Serif and supports fractional characters (up to one-tenth), I would also accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by upto one-tenth.

I have a sample code for you, try if it works for you

```
nupdwn.Minimum = -10;
nupdwn.Maximum = 10;
nupdwn.Increment = 0.25;
nupdwn.DecimalPlaces = 2;
```

Comment: What I meant was the use of an actual fraction, such as one over ten, not 0.01.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Sans Serif does support fractional characters:

[image]

I will try to program a derived NumericUpDown to show fractional values. If it succeeds, i will share the code here...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Sample-Code for a FractionalUpDown.

Be sure to set `DecimalPlaces` to your needs.

With `Mode`, you can choose the formatting of the value:

- `EMode.Decimal` => 2,500.
- `EMode.Fractional` => ⁵⁄₂
- `EMode.FractionalMixed` => 2 ¹⁄₂
- `EMode.FractionalASCII` => 5/2
- `EMode.FractionalMixedASCII` => 2 1/2

Code:

```
public class FractionalUpDown: NumericUpDown {
    //Hide Hexadecimal
    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [Bindable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public new bool Hexadecimal {
        get { return false; }
        set { base.Hexadecimal = false; }
    }

    private EMode mode;

    [DefaultValue(EMode.Fractional)]
    public EMode Mode {
        get { return mode; }
        set {
            if (value != mode) {
                mode = value;
                UpdateEditText();
            }
        }
    }

    public enum EMode {
        Fractional,
        FractionalMixed,
        FractionalASCII,
        FractionalMixedASCII,
        Decimal
    }

    public FractionalUpDown() {

    }

    protected override void UpdateEditText() {
        if (Mode == EMode.Decimal) {
            base.UpdateEditText();
            return;
        }

        double accuracy = Math.Pow(10.0, -(DecimalPlaces + 1));
        if (accuracy > 0.1) accuracy = 0.1;
        this.Text = FractionToString(DoubleToFraction((double)Value, accuracy), Mode);
    }

    public struct Fraction {
        public Fraction(int n, int d) {
            N = n;
            D = d;
        }

        public int N { get; private set; }
        public int D { get; private set; }
    }

    private static readonly char[] numbers = new char[10] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
    private static readonly char[] numerators = new char[10] { '⁰', '¹', '²', '³', '⁴', '⁵', '⁶', '⁷', '⁸', '⁹' };
    private static readonly char[] denumerators = new char[10] { '₀', '₁', '₂', '₃', '₄', '₅', '₆', '₇', '₈', '₉' };

    protected string FractionToString(Fraction frac, EMode mode) {
        int full = 0;
        int n = frac.N;
        string result = string.Empty;

        bool mixed = mode == EMode.FractionalMixed ||
                     mode == EMode.FractionalMixedASCII;

        bool useFractionalChars = mode == EMode.Fractional ||
                                  mode == EMode.FractionalMixed;

        if (mixed && Math.Abs(frac.N) >= frac.D) {
            full = frac.N / frac.D;
            n = Math.Abs(frac.N % frac.D);

            if (full != 0) result = full.ToString();
            else if (n == 0) return "0";
        }

        if (n != 0) {
            string fracNtext = n.ToString();
            string fracDtext = frac.D.ToString();

            if (useFractionalChars) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) fracNtext = fracNtext.Replace(numbers[i], numerators[i]);
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) fracDtext = fracDtext.Replace(numbers[i], denumerators[i]);
            } else {
                if (full != 0) result += " ";
            }
            result += fracNtext + '⁄' + fracDtext;
        } else {
            //Fractional Part == 0/?
            if (full == 0) {
                if (mixed == true) {
                    return "0";
                } else {
                    if (useFractionalChars) {
                        return numerators[0].ToString() + '⁄' + denumerators[1].ToString();
                    } else {
                        return numbers[0].ToString() + '⁄' + numbers[1].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }


    //Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124743/algorithm-for-simplifying-decimal-to-fractions/32903747#32903747
    protected Fraction DoubleToFraction(double value, double accuracy) {
        if (accuracy <= 0.0 || accuracy >= 1.0) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("accuracy", "Must be > 0 and < 1.");
        }

        int sign = Math.Sign(value);

        if (sign == -1) {
            value = Math.Abs(value);
        }

        // Accuracy is the maximum relative error; convert to absolute maxError
        double maxError = sign == 0 ? accuracy : value * accuracy;

        int n = (int)Math.Floor(value);
        value -= n;

        if (value < maxError) {
            return new Fraction(sign * n, 1);
        }

        if (1 - maxError < value) {
            return new Fraction(sign * (n + 1), 1);
        }

        // The lower fraction is 0/1
        int lower_n = 0;
        int lower_d = 1;

        // The upper fraction is 1/1
        int upper_n = 1;
        int upper_d = 1;

        while (true) {
            // The middle fraction is (lower_n + upper_n) / (lower_d + upper_d)
            int middle_n = lower_n + upper_n;
            int middle_d = lower_d + upper_d;

            if (middle_d * (value + maxError) < middle_n) {
                // real + error < middle : middle is our new upper
                Seek(ref upper_n, ref upper_d, lower_n, lower_d, (un, ud) => (lower_d + ud) * (value + maxError) < (lower_n + un));
                upper_n = middle_n;
                upper_d = middle_d;
            } else if (middle_n < (value - maxError) * middle_d) {
                // middle < real - error : middle is our new lower
                Seek(ref lower_n, ref lower_d, upper_n, upper_d, (ln, ld) => (ln + upper_n) < (value - maxError) * (ld + upper_d));
                lower_n = middle_n;
                lower_d = middle_d;
            } else {
                // Middle is our best fraction
                return new Fraction((n * middle_d + middle_n) * sign, middle_d);
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Binary seek for the value where f() becomes false.
    /// Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124743/algorithm-for-simplifying-decimal-to-fractions/32903747#32903747
    /// </summary>
    protected void Seek(ref int a, ref int b, int ainc, int binc, Func<int, int, bool> f) {
        a += ainc;
        b += binc;

        if (f(a, b)) {
            int weight = 1;

            do {
                weight *= 2;
                a += ainc * weight;
                b += binc * weight;
            }
            while (f(a, b));

            do {
                weight /= 2;

                int adec = ainc * weight;
                int bdec = binc * weight;

                if (!f(a - adec, b - bdec)) {
                    a -= adec;
                    b -= bdec;
                }
            }
            while (weight > 1);
        }
    }
}
```