# How to display fraction instead of decimal (double) in android TextView (answerview)

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to show fractions instead of decimal value in a textView(answerview)

For example - 1.0625 (This value is an answer from some calculation)

I want to show 1.0625 in fractions (Added a sample image [Required fraction image])
[image]
 like 1(1/16) in textView.

This is not a constant value, the value keeps changing according to user calculations, so for every answer I want to convert into fractions and display

Sujay

Comment: To turn a `double` into a fraction, try http://stackoverflow.com/a/31586500/984823 - As you know doubles are inprecise from the start, so an approximation must be sought, do not expect to be able to reduce `10625/10000` (by gcd).

Answer (score 4):

Use [kexanie](https://github.com/kexanie/MathView) to do that

In your case you should set text in your `MathView` [read kexanie README.md]

```
String text = "$$" + var1 + "\\frac{" + var2 + "}{" + var3 + "}$$";
```

[image]

Here `var1 = 1`, `var2 = 1` and `var3 = 16`

Add a MathView in your xml

```
<io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
    android:id="@+id/formula"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    auto:engine="KaTeX"
    >
</io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>
```

Then in onCreate() method

```
MathView mathv = (MathView) findViewById(R.id.formula);
```

and finally set your formula to `mathv`

```
mathv.setText(text);
```

Or you can use other libraries mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784786/mathml-and-java/1792641#1792641)