# Detect if a double is a perfect square in Java

Tags: math, double, pow, sqrt, math.sqrt

I want to detect if a double, like 6.25 is a perfect square or not.

To detect perfect squares for those numbers whose square root is an integer, I would do something like

```
public boolean isPerfectDouble( double i )
    {
        if (Double.isInfinite(i)) {
            return false;
        }
        double sqrt = Math.sqrt(i);
        return sqrt == Math.floor(sqrt) && sqrt*sqrt == i;
    }
```

However, this would not work for numbers like 6.25, which is indeed a perfect square.

Comment: What is a "perfect square" in terms of decimal fractions? A square of a finite decimal fraction? In binary? Note that in floating point numbers, `0.1*0.1` results in `0.010000000000000002` as `0.1` can not be exactly represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you would need exact representation of such numbers. Probably you would want to truncate after certain decimal places. Then multiply the number by integer power of `100` until you get an integer. Check it the integer is square or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to interpret your assertion that 6.25 is a perfect square because it is the square of a rational number (numbers of the form p/q where p and q are both integer numbers).

This differs from Santosh Linkhas solution where 
a perfect square is take to be a square of an integer times a negative power of 10.

The key difference is that I would consider `1/9 = 0.111111...` to be a perfect square since it is `1/3 = 0.33333...` squared.

The interesting part of this problem is that all doubles are rationals, but not all rationals are expressible as doubles.

What I suggest is the following: Find out if there is a good rational approximation to the square-root of the value - [Algorithm for simplifying decimal to fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124743/algorithm-for-simplifying-decimal-to-fractions/42085412) is a really good starting point.