# Keep recieving errors as I attempt to use a function to replace the power function, namely when raising to 1/2

Tags: python, python-2.7

For an assignment, I must create a program with a function that replaces the "power function" assuming that it is broken for whatever reason. The current model I have works pretty decently, but I'm struggling to get it to work when raising to a 1/2, 1/4, etc. (essentially performing a square root function). I know that the issue lies within floats not cooperating with range, but I personally don't know how to avoid this

```
def power (value, exp):
    num = 1.0 
    if exp>0:
        for function in range(exp):
            num = num * value 
    elif exp<0:
        for function in range(-exp):
            num = num / value
    else:
        num = 1
    return num

number = float(raw_input("Please enter a the base number you wish to raise to a power (no fractions, decimal allowed): "))
exponent = float(raw_input("Please enter the power you wish to raise the base number to (no fractions, decimal allowed): "))

print "Your base number was:", number
print "You rasied this number to the power of:", exponent
print "The ending product of this operation is:", power(number, exponent)
```

Comment: I get that you're trying to replace `pow()`, but is the `**` operator really off limits?

Comment: @tobias_k , if the exp was 1/2 it would fall under the first if statement, as this is a positive value.

Comment: @kwinkunks Sadly yes, the point of it is to test our logical reasoning, not our use of python functions

Comment: @Christian your `elif` could simply be `num = 1/power(value, -exp)` if you are assuming integer exponents up to that point.

Comment: Is [using logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_via_logarithms) okay?

Comment: @tobias_k I would consider that as cheating

Comment: @tobias_k Now I am listening.. xD

Comment: Unless the exponent is an irrational number, it's a fraction, e.g. two integers.Knowing that you can avoid floats in `range()`.

Answer (score 0):

Fractional powers are a bit tricky, but you can use the fact that b<sup>n/d</sup> = (b<sup>n</sup>)<sup>1/d</sup> = <sup>d</sup>√ b<sup>n</sup>. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents) for details. So you could write a recursive algorithm that

- reduces the exponent until it is a float between 0 and 1
- approximates a fraction `n/d` representing that float, e.g. using [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fractions.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5128558/1639625)
- find the `d`th root of the `n` power, e.g. using simple binary search

Code:

```
def power(b, e):
    # the simple cases
    if e == 0: return 1
    if b in (0, 1): return b
    if e < 0: return 1 / power(b, -e)
    if e >= 1: return b * power(b, e - 1)
    # fractions: b^(n/d) == d-/ b^n
    n, d = float_to_fraction(e)  # see linked answer
    return root(power(b, n), d)

def root(x, r):
    if x < 0: raise ValueError("No roots of negative numbers!")
    low, high = 0, x
    cur = (low + high) / 2
    while high - low > 0.001:
        if power(cur, r) < x:
            low = cur
        else:
            high = cur
        cur = (low + high) / 2
    return cur
```

Example:

```
>>> b, e = 1.23, -4.56
>>> b**e
0.38907443175580797
>>> power(b, e))
0.38902984218983117
```

Or you could just use [logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_via_logarithms), although that might be considered cheating:

```
>>> math.exp(e * math.log(b))
0.38907443175580797
```

Comment: Addendum: Of course, the same could be implemented iteratively instead of using recursion and would probably be faster this way, but that should not really be a concern here and I like the elegance of the recursive definition. Also, there are certainly better ways to compute the nth root, but again, that's not really the point of the question.