# Formatting fraction numbers in Pascal

Tags: delphi, floating-point, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

I need to print values that are in a matrix, these may vary from integer to real. As an example a matrix that my program use, named *kernel*, is shown below:

```
kernel[0,0]:= 1/16;
kernel[0,1]:= 2/16;
kernel[0,2]:= 1/16;
kernel[1,0]:= 2/16;
kernel[1,1]:= 4/16;
kernel[1,2]:= 2/16;
kernel[2,0]:= 1/16;
kernel[2,1]:= 2/16;
kernel[2,2]:= 1/16;
```

the issue comes when printing each of them, because I couldn't find a way to print a number like `1/16` in a easy-to-read way, the program displays something like `6.2500000000000000000000000000E-2` which is OK but I would prefer to have something more aesthetic like `0.0625` or even better `1/16`. Does anyone acknowledge a way of formatting that allows me to do so?

Comment: `1/16` is not a number, it's an operation. If you want to display `1/16`, you'll need to do so in a string. You can use `RoundTo` to truncate to a specific number of decimal places, but doing so will affect the accuracy of calculations with the value. For display purposes, you can use `FormatFloat` or `Format` to only display part of the decimal values wihtout any loss of accuracy in the value itself.

Comment: Accuracy is not something that I care much about in this context, so I'm gonna use RoundTo... Thank you Ken

Comment: You might when you try to add them up again. :-) Also, `2/16` is properly `1/8`, and `4/16` is `1/4`.

Comment: If you problem is to display the numbers, you can use Format('%5.3f', [Kernel[0,0]); which returns a string with the number "formatted" with a length of 5 and 3 decimal places. 1/16 will becomes "0.625". There are a lot of options, look at the documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.Format

Comment: Maybe this is want you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124743/algorithm-for-simplifying-decimal-to-fractions

Comment: `RoundTo` doesn't seem like the right solution to me. This is something that you should do at the formatting stage. You don't need to make a new floating point value.

Comment: What do you know about the denominator? If it's always 16 then it should be easy to display as a fraction. Just multiply the number by 16 and then write that number divided by 16. If the denominator can be anything then it's more difficult. Writing 1/3 as a fraction is difficult because precision will be lost when stored as a single number. The best way when dealing with inputs and outputs as fractions is to store the numerators and denominators separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each array element holds the *value* of the fraction.

To write the value as a *fraction* you can simply calculate the numerator as the product of the array element and the denominator.

I prefer to use the `Format()` function for display formatting.

Given the array you show, two index variables, `a` and `b` and the denominator

```
denominator := 16;
for a := 0 to 2 do
  for b := 0 to 2 do
  begin
    s := format('kernel[%d,%d] = %d/%d',[a,b,round(kernel[a,b]*denominator),denominator]);
    memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  end;
```

Comment: If the kernel is a large matrix, like 100×100 or 1000×1000, it is important not to forget `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` (with `try..finally` protection, of course).

Comment: Yes @Andreas That would be important when printing 10000 or 1000000 lines

Comment: Thank you Tom and Andreas. The kernel that I'm using has 3x3 dimensions so it won't be necessary, thank you!