# How to calculate the parameter values for a fractional frequency divider with post-scaler

Tags: algorithm, math, embedded

I need to calculate the parameter for a fractional frequency divider on a micro-controller:

```
fout = fin / (i + n/d) / p
```

for a given fin and fout.
All parameters are integers with the following allowed ranges:

```
i: integer part 2..256
d: divisor 1..512
n: dividend 0..511
p: post-scaler 1..64
```

The calculation has to be done on the controller itself and should be reasonably fast (around 1 ms)

A simple approach using brute-force searching through all 32768 possible d/p combinations
(with different rounding for n and i to check for above/below) will be too slow.
Using only the lowest possible p to keep i below 256 would miss better fitting parameters.

Is there a suitable algorithm to calculate the parameters?
The closest question i could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69832929/finding-a-rational-approximation-of-a-real-number-when-both-the-numerator-and-de)
but this does not really give a solutions and does not include the additional complexity of the post-scaler.

If there is no clever algorithm, what optimizations for the brute-force approach are possible?
One easy one is to only check for d 256..512 because for d 1..255 there is a combination with identical value in the upper half.
Is it somehow possible to eliminate some d/p combination that are also redundant?

I need different parameter sets depending on the situation:

1. the parameters that produce the closest possible fout above a given frequency.
2. the parameters that produce the closest possible fout below a given frequency.
3. the parameters that produce the closest possible or exact fout for a given frequency.

1 and 2 will be used to increase/decrease the fout by the smallest possible steps.

Comment: Can you add some brackets into your equation? Triple-decker fractions like a/b/c don't mean anything to me!  Also, don't forget that other factor that you maybe should prefer even divisors in order to get a more stable clock.

Comment: what is the required range for fin/fout?

Comment: are the `fin,fout` integer or not? can you use `float/double` or not?

Comment: I updated code in my answer had a silly bug in there now the int version matches precision of the float version ...

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**: I'm leaving the original answer, even though I figured out how to make it provably correct.  I'll insert that at the bottom.

---

Here is an approach that will find a **good** answer very quickly.  I don't have a proof, but I think it will always be optimal. If not always, then often.

If we rearrange:

```
fout = fin / (i + n/d) / p
```

we get

```
fin / fout = (i + n/d) * p = (d*i*p + n*p) / d
```

So we're looking for a small fraction that comes close to a known number, that you can create from your parameters.

Now let's talk about the [Stern-Brocot Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree).  (Incidentally Brocot was a clock maker trying to come up with good gearing systems, which isn't that different from your problem.)

Suppose that `x` is a positive number.  We start the tree with:

```
0 / 1 < x  < 1 / 0 (aka infinity)
```

(It is usual to start with `1` instead of infinity on the right, but this works and lets you handle numbers bigger than `1`.)

At each step we have:

```
a / b < x < c / d
```

Our next guess is `(a + c) / (b + d)`.  We compare that, replace one side, and continue.

The numbers we generate turn out to include all of the best possible rational approximations.  Meaning that if we have `a / b` in this sequence, then there is no fraction with denominator smaller than `b` that is as good an approximation.  And any fraction with that property WILL occur in this sequence.

Let's demonstrate it on finding approximations to `e = 2.718281828459045` with a denominator at most `512`.  This is doable by hand.

```
   0 /   1 < e <    1 /   0, guess    1 /   1 = 1                 < e
   1 /   1 < e <    1 /   0, guess    2 /   1 = 2                 < e
   2 /   1 < e <    1 /   0, guess    3 /   1 = 3                 > e
   2 /   1 < e <    3 /   1, guess    5 /   2 = 2.5               < e
   5 /   2 < e <    3 /   1, guess    8 /   3 = 2.666666666666666 < e
   8 /   3 < e <    3 /   1, guess   11 /   4 = 2.75              > e
   8 /   3 < e <   11 /   4, guess   19 /   7 = 2.714285714285714 < e
  19 /   7 < e <   11 /   4, guess   30 /  11 = 2.727272727272727 > e
  19 /   7 < e <   30 /  11, guess   49 /  18 = 2.722222222222222 > e
  19 /   7 < e <   49 /  18, guess   68 /  25 = 2.72              > e
  19 /   7 < e <   68 /  25, guess   87 /  32 = 2.7185            > e
  19 /   7 < e <   87 /  32, guess  106 /  39 = 2.717948717948718 < e
 106 /  39 < e <   87 /  32, guess  193 /  71 = 2.718309859154929 > e
 106 /  39 < e <  193 /  71, guess  299 / 110 = 2.718181818181818 < e
 299 / 110 < e <  193 /  71, guess  492 / 181 = 2.718232044198895 < e
 492 / 181 < e <  193 /  71, guess  685 / 252 = 2.718253968253968 < e
 685 / 252 < e <  193 /  71, guess  878 / 323 = 2.718266253869969 < e
 878 / 323 < e <  193 /  71, guess 1071 / 394 = 2.718274111675127 < e
1071 / 394 < e <  193 /  71, guess 1264 / 465 = 2.718279569892473 < e
1264 / 465 < e <  193 /  71, guess 1457 / 536 ...and we're out of range
```

Optimization note, the first few steps are literally just finding what integers you're between.  You can skip them by starting with `int(fin/fout) / 1 <= x < (1 + int(fin/fout)) / 1`.  From there, at most `511` guesses are needed, and usually you need considerably less than that.

And now our candidates for a good fraction below the number we want are:

```
1264/465, 1071/394, 878/323, ...
```

And our candidates for a good fraction above the number we want are:

```
193/71, 87/32, 68/25, ...
```

Now how do we try to meet the parameters?  Well, we have the following rules.  If the fraction we want is `a/b` then:

1. `d = b`
2. `p` is at most `min(64, a//d//2)` where `//` is integer division. (If `p < 1` then no solution.)
3. `p` divides `a` and is as large as possible.
4. `i = min(a//p//d, 256)`.
5. `n = a//p - i*d` and we don't find a solution if `511 < n`.

Now let's attempt to get the lower bound `1264/465`.

1. `d = b = 465`
2. `p` is at most `min(64, a//d//2) = 1`. Note that `a//d` is the integer component of `a/b` which will usually be the integer part of `fout/fin`.  So the upper bound on `p` in practice is simply `min(int(fin/fout/2), 64)`.
3. `p = 1`.
4. `i = min(a//p//d, 256) = min(1264//1//465, 256) = min(2, 256) = 2`
5. `n = a//p - i*d = 1264//1 - 2*465 = 334`

We don't have to look at the next lower bound because this one worked.

Now let's try to get the upper bound `193/71`.

1. `d = b = 71`
2. `p` is at most `min(64, a//d//2) = 1`.
3. `p = 1`.
4. `i = min(a//p//d, 256) = min(193//1//71, 256) = 2`.
5. `n = a//p - i*d = 193//1//71 - 2*71 = 51`

We don't have to look at the next upper bound because this one worked.

Side note: The cases where you have to check multiple bounds to get an answer will be when `1 < p` is required.  So `256 < fin/fout`.

I know this was a lot of writing.  But a calculation that can be written out by hand like this should be able to be executed on your microcontroller well within the desired millisecond.

---

OK, the above did not always work at the top end of the range.  Here is a fix.

First of all, `p` only has a maximum of `64` values.  So only a finite and generally small list of values for `p` will leave us with

```
2 <= fin / fout / p < 257
```

For each of them we have `i = int(fin / fout / p)`.  If we have an integer then `n = 0` and `d = 1`.  Else we just need to find `n/d` by walking the Stern-Brocot tree as above.

So for each of at most 64 values of `p` get a candidate upper and lower candidate.  And then pick the best one as your final answer.

If that's too slow, there are possible speedups with either continued fractions, or a binary search past the long stretches of `< x` over and over again.  But I suspect that the complexity won't pay for itself with such small numbers.

Answer (score 0):

OK I see it like this (C++):

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct divider_cfg
    {
    // fout = (fin / (i + n/d)) / p
    unsigned int i; // integer part 2..256
    unsigned int n; // dividend 0..511
    unsigned int d; // divisor 1..512
    unsigned int p; // post-scaler 1..64
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
float get_fout(float fin,const divider_cfg &cfg)
    {
    float d;
    d=cfg.n; d/=cfg.d; d+=cfg.i; d/=cfg.p;
    return fin/d;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void get_cfg_f32(float fin,float fout,divider_cfg &cfg)
    {
    // fout = (fin / (i + n/d)) / p
    float d0,d1,d,dd;
    divider_cfg c;
    d0=fin/fout;                            // wanted divider
    dd=512.0;                               // initial error (bigger than possible)
    for (c.p=1;c.p<=64;c.p++)               // brute force p
        {
        d1=d0/c.p; c.i=floor(d1); d1-=c.i;  // compute i from p
        for (c.d=1;c.d<=512;c.d++)          // brute force d
            {
            c.n=floor(d1*c.d);              // compute n from d
            d=c.n; d/=c.d; d+=c.i; d/=c.p;  // compute divider
            d=fabs(d-d0);                   // compute error
            if (d<dd){ dd=d; cfg=c; }       // remember better config
            }
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// this enables float computation of the wanted divider for better precision
// the search itself is not using float so it does not affect speed too much

    #define _use_float
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef _use_float
void get_cfg_u32(float fin,float fout,divider_cfg &cfg)
#else
void get_cfg_u32(unsigned int fin,unsigned int fout,divider_cfg &cfg)
#endif
    {
    // fout = (fin / (i + n/d)) / p
    // (i + n/d)*p = fin/fout
    // (i + n/d) = (fin/fout)/p
    unsigned int idn,d0,d,dd,sh;
    divider_cfg c;

    #ifndef _use_float
    // d0 = wanted divider no FPU
    // lower precision on 32 bits need more
    unsigned int di,df;
    sh=32-9;                                // fixed point shift: log2(max_unsigned_int) - 9
    di=fin/fout;
    df=fin%fout;
    for (d=0,dd=1;dd<=df;d++,dd<<=1);       // d = ceil(log2(df))
    d+=sh;                                  // number of bits required for (df<<sh)
    if (d<=32) d=0; else d-=32;             // d number of rounded bits to prevent overflow of (df<<sh)
    d0=(di<<sh) + ((df<<(sh-d))/(fout>>d)); // wanted divider   (fin<<sh)/fout
    #else
    // d0 = wanted divider using FPU
    sh=32-9;                                // fixed point shift: log2(max_unsigned_int) - 9
    float fd=float(fin)/float(fout);
    fd*=1<<sh; d0=fd;                       // wanted divider   (fin<<sh)/fout
    #endif

    dd=0xFFFFFFFF;                          // initial error (biggest possible)
    for (c.p=1;c.p<=64;c.p++)               // brute force p
     for (c.d=1;c.d<=512;c.d++)             // brute force d
        {
        if (c.d==508)
         c.d=c.d;

        d=d0/c.p;                           //  = (i<<sh) + ((n<<sh)/d) = (fin<<sh)/(fout*p)
        c.i=d>>sh;
        d-=c.i<<sh;                         //  = ((n<<sh)/d)
        c.n=(d*c.d)>>sh;

        d=((c.i<<sh)+((c.n<<sh)/c.d))/c.p;  // compute divider << sh
        d=abs(d-d0);                        // compute error
        if (d<dd){ dd=d; cfg=c; }           // remember better config
        }
    }
#undef _use_float
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the integer version assumes 32bit unsigned integer type... both versions brute force `p,d` and recomputes the rest remembering better solution. The integer version uses configuration `#define _use_float` which enables more precise divider computation, in case your platform does not have `float` at all or you have more than 32bit integers you can use the fully integer version (just rewrite all the `32` to whatever bitwidth you have)

ON my old PC its:

```
              fin  = 16000000.00
              fout = 3005000.00
[  10.696 ms] fout (f32) =   3005002.25 err(        2.25) f32 | ((  5)+(134/413))/  1
[   1.305 ms] fout (i32) =   3005002.25 err(        2.25) u32 | ((  5)+(134/413))/  1
```

however on MCU it will be slower of coarse and without FPU I would definately go for the u32 (fixed point) version (its precision using the `_use_float` is the same as float version anyway).

The `sh` is precision (number of bits after decimal point) of fixed point math. I made changes so overflow should not occur anymore.